# Deleting an Item from array of a table column in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

There is a Posts table that has a column named images. in images I store data as JSON array as:

```
["p1.jpg", "p2.jpg","p4.jpg","p9.jpg","p11.jpg", "p12.jpg","p13.jpg", "p14.jpg"];
```

I want to delete one of these images by ajax. I send the id and image by ajax and get that id and image in the controller correctly:

```
  public function remove() {

$imgs = Image::where('id', request()->id)->pluck('images');
return $imgs;
  }

reults in console:
[Array(8)]
0: (8) ["p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p4.jpg", "p9.jpg", "p11.jpg", "p12.jpg", "p13.jpg", "p14.jpg"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

also, I get the image name by request()->img from ajax.

```
$image = request()->img; => p12.jpg
```

How I can delete the $image from $images array?

Comment: what is the field `images` store, a string like `"p1.jpg"` or a JSON array?

Comment: Just use an update query to overwrite the `images` column with the new array?

Comment: ["p1.jpg", "p2.jpg","p4.jpg","p9.jpg","p11.jpg", "p12.jpg","p13.jpg", "p14.jpg"]

Comment: already tested didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You may cast images `attr` to array in your Image model

```
//App\Image
protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
];
```

Then in your remove function :

```
public function remove() {
  if(request()->id && request()->img) {
     $imgModel = Image::findOrFail(request()->id);
     $imgs = $imgModel->images;

     // find request()->img position inside imgs array
     $position = array_search(request()->img, $imgs);

     // delete request()->img
     unset($imgs[$position]);

     $imgModel->images = array_values($imgs);
     $imgModel->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: this return the index:

foreach ($imgs as $v){
  $position =  array_search(request()->img, $v);
}
 => 5 or ...

Comment: COuld you dump $imgs result and paste it here ?

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#294 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "p1.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "p2.jpg"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "p4.jpg"
      [3]=>
      string(6) "p9.jpg"
      [4]=>
      string(7) "p11.jpg"
      [5]=>
      string(7) "p12.jpg"
      [6]=>
      string(7) "p13.jpg"
      [7]=>
      string(7) "p14.jpg"
    }
  }
}

Comment: yes. it worked. thank you **Foued**, you did great. it is the best solution in StackOverflow about deleting an item from an array.